# When self signing a key in `gpa`, what is the purpose of the "sign only locally" option, and what does it do?

Tags: gnupg

What does this "sign only locally" check box do or mean in `gpa` (the GNU Privacy Assistant)?

[image]

*I'm working on verifying the fingerprints of acquired public keys, and once verified with their owner, then self signing these keys to signify that I've checked their authenticity.*

Answer (score 1):

**It means if you export the key** (e.g. with `gpg --export ...`) **that this signature will not be exported with the key into the export output file**.

---

Comparing the similar utilities **`gpa`** with **`kgpg`** (where KGpg is KDE's key management utility) you can see the similar, but more enlightening check box:

[image]